# Как правильно данные расставить в таблице?

Tags: symfony, twig

Есить запись в таблице

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код контроллера:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Day;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;



class DefaultController extends AbstractController


{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="default")
     */
    public function index()
    {

    // $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    // $menu = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();


    return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'DefaultController',
        'users' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(User::class)->findAll(),
        'day' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Day::class)->findAll(),
    ]);

}

}
```

Код Index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %} 
{% block title %}Hello DefaultController!{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

{% for user in users %}

{# <h2>{{ user.name }}</h2>
<p>{{ user.day }}</p>
<p>{{ user.project }}</p> #}



{% endfor %}
<table class="table">

<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">Проект</th>
{% for days in day %}
    <th scope="col">{{ days.day }}т</th>        
{% endfor %}    
</tr>
</thead>


{% for user in users %}
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>{{ user.project }}</td>        

    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Как сделать такой вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно такой запрос применить

```
SELECT t.`progect`,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t1.`name` SEPARATOR ', ') FROM `table` AS t1 WHERE t1.`progect` = t.project AND t1.`day` = 1) AS 'пн',
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t1.`name` SEPARATOR ', ') FROM `table` AS t1 WHERE t1.`progect` = t.project AND t1.`day` = 2) AS 'вт',
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t1.`name` SEPARATOR ', ') FROM `table` AS t1 WHERE t1.`progect` = t.project AND t1.`day` = 3) AS 'ср',
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t1.`name` SEPARATOR ', ') FROM `table` AS t1 WHERE t1.`progect` = t.project AND t1.`day` = 4) AS 'чт',
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t1.`name` SEPARATOR ', ') FROM `table` AS t1 WHERE t1.`progect` = t.project AND t1.`day` = 5) AS 'пт',
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t1.`name` SEPARATOR ', ') FROM `table` AS t1 WHERE t1.`progect` = t.project AND t1.`day` = 6) AS 'сб'
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t1.`name` SEPARATOR ', ') FROM `table` AS t1 WHERE t1.`progect` = t.project AND t1.`day` = 7) AS 'вс'
FROM `table` AS t
GROUP BY t.`project`
```

А можете обычный селект, преобразовать в нужную вам таблицу с помощью массивов в PHP